# Properly extending a class in C++

Tags: c++, macos, class, object, composition

with this code:

```
class Plant
{
public:
    virtual std::string getPlantName();
    virtual void setPlantName(std::string s);

    virtual std::string getPlantType();
    virtual void setPlantType(std::string s);


};

class Carrot : public Plant
{
public:
    Carrot();
    ~Carrot();

private:
    std::string _plantName;

};
```

and then:

```
#include "Carrot.hpp"

Carrot::Carrot() 
{ 


}

Carrot::~Carrot() { }

std::string Carrot::getPlantName() { return _plantName; }
```

I am getting a link error:

```
Carrot.cpp:16:21: Out-of-line definition of 'getPlantName' does not match any declaration in 'Carrot'
```

So the goal here is to create a Plant class where other classes extend like `class Carrot : public Plant`

But, what I am not sure about is could I just `inline` the functionality in `Plant` so that I dont have to create these `get` and `set` functions in each class like Carrot or Peas, etc?

if I did:

```
inline virtual std::string getPlantName( return _plantName; );
```

would that work? I would then add `std::string _PlantName;` to `class Plant` and then when I  create `Carrot` from `Plant` I get all the same functions and `Carrot` will have variables like `_plantName`, etc, correct?

So this would be:

```
class Plant
{
public:
    inline virtual std::string getPlantName( return _plantName; );
    virtual void setPlantName(std::string s);

    virtual std::string getPlantType();
    virtual void setPlantType(std::string s);

private:
    std::string _plantName;
};

class Carrot : public Plant
{
public:
    Carrot();
    ~Carrot();
};

#include "Carrot.hpp"

Carrot::Carrot() 
{ 
    setPlantName(CARROT::plantName);

}

Carrot::~Carrot() { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all objects of the `Plant` class should have a type and a name, both `std::string`s, you probably want those common members in the base class:

```
// Plant.hpp
class Plant
{
public:
    Plant(); 
    virtual ~Plant(); // virtual destructor!
    virtual std::string getPlantName();
    virtual void setPlantName(std::string s);
    virtual std::string getPlantType();
    virtual void setPlantType(std::string s);
protected:
    std::string _plantName;
    std::string _plantType;
};

// Plant.cpp
#include <Plant.hpp>

std::string Plant::getPlantName() { return _plantName; }
void Plant::setPlantName(std::string s) { _plantName = s; }
... same for type
```

When creating a derived class using `class Carrot : public Plant`, that class will have the same data members and the same functions. You would also have the ability to override them if needed (thanks to the `virtual` keyword, derived classes' implementations will be called when using a `Plant` pointer to a `Carrot` object).

Note that if you want to make sure never to instansiate a `Plant` object, you should make any non-common functions (like a `DoSomethingTypeSpecific()` that a Carrot or a Flower would do differently) **pure virtual** and by that creating an **abstract base class**. All base classes would then *have* to implement those functions.

Inlining here does not make a real difference, it's just a matter of defining the functions in the header or in a separate .cpp file. Generally, it's a good idea to keep the implementation in a separate file but these small setters and getters could easily be inlined if you wanted to.

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to do. All `Plants` have these same items (and other I haven't included) and when extending I want all of these same things and override where needed.

Comment: and so to inline in the header it would be `inline virtual std....`. or `virtual inline ...` the order doesn't make a difference (i believe) but is there a generally expected way a developer might want to read it?

Comment: can you elaborate on the `pure virtual`? can you `pure virtual inline` those getter and setters?

Comment: oh, I see `= 0` means that I *have* to have each class of Plants define these functions, even though they all will do exactly the same and set and get a data member. So I could not make those pure virtual, but make pure virtual functions that each may implement but perform differently.

Comment: The pure virtual would be well suited for something that the classes need to do differently, not the ones you used (I'll rephrase my answer)!

Answer (score 0):

You could correct the error by adding the method to the class declaration:

```
class Carrot : public Plant
{
public:
   Carrot();
   ~Carrot();

  virtual std::string getPlantName();

private:
  std::string _plantName;

};
```

Or, if all plants have names, you could define the method in the Plant class instead (likely in in plant.cpp). In fact, you have to define it unless you declare it to be pure virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function.

```
class Carrot : public Plant
{
public:
    Carrot();
    ~Carrot();

    std::string getPlantName(); //Add this

private:
    std::string _plantName;

};
```

A couple of notes:

- It isn't strictly necessary for `Carrot::getPlantName` to be virtual, although many C++ developers consider it good form. I personally prefer to only use virtuals in abstract base classes, and use none in concrete classes
- You probabally need to add `virtual ~Plant() {}` to the `Plant` class. You almost always want classes with virtual methods to also have virtual destructors.